# Align separate native HTML web component into a table or grid

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, native-web-component

I have a like a spreadsheet of data (rows and columns), and I am converting to web components. It makes sense to make each column a web component. However some of the fields may require more vertical space than others. I could set a max height and scroll within the box, but I would prefer for the "row", i.e. the nth cell of each column, to be the same height. How would you make it such that it always appears as a grid?

In the example below "cell" `A2` and `B2` do not align vertically because they are independant. How does one insert webcomponents into a `<table>` or a `display: grid` element when the web component needs span multiple rows, but keep the rows aligned?

```js
class Component extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super().attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE");
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        if (this.initialised) return; // Prevent initialising twice is item is moved
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.initialised = true;
            this.init();
        });
    }
    get(id) {
        return this.shadowRoot.getElementById(id);
    }
    init(required = true) {
        const prev = this.previousElementSibling;
        let props = JSON.parse(prev.textContent);
        this.props = props;
    }
    set props(value) {
        this.get('TEXTAREA1').textContent = value.textarea1;
        this.get('TEXTAREA2').textContent = value.textarea2;
    }
}
window.customElements.define('wc-column', Component);
```

```css
#CONTAINER {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE">
<style>
    :host {
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid lime;
    }
    #TEXTAREA1, #TEXTAREA2 {
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div id="TEXTAREA1"></div>
<div id="TEXTAREA2"></div>
</template>

<div id="CONTAINER">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "textarea1": "Cell A1", 
            "textarea2": "Cell A2"
        }
    </script>
    <wc-column></wc-column>
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "textarea1": "Cell B1 - Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum",
            "textarea2": "Cell B2 - Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum"
        }
    </script>
    <wc-column></wc-column>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try with ``display:grid``? Looks like you want a container element with shadowDOM and a CSS Grid inside, and then content in components without shadowDOM to position them in the CSS grid. Also look into named grid-areas. Learning: https://cssgridgarden.com/

Comment: Hi Danny, I am familiar with CSS grids, and have played cssgridgarden before thank you! Yes sounds like I can't have a column component, but need a cell component, and place those in the grid. But would be much easier to have a column component, then say 12 separate cell components. The main problem is aligning content in a shadow DOM with content in another components shadow DOM

Comment: Just like positioning something in a DIV does *not* affect positioning something *else* in a following DIV. Your first column does not affect anything in the following column.

Comment: I agree, I am not expecting it to align up, I wish to come up with a strategy on how to make it line up.

Comment: Investigate ``is``, ``has`` and ``where`` selectors. https://web.dev/css-is-and-where/

Comment: I currently use `:is()` often (and `:where()` is the same functionally). and `:has()` is not mainstream yet, but I don't seen how they would help? I am guessing one will have to resort to javasacript, maybe a resize observer

Comment: No need for a resize observer; make your first column/component set a ``--rowheight`` CSS property at a shared parentNode (or even document level). All other columns/components can then automagically resize

Comment: The issue is later columns may require more space. I need something like a <table> element, that works across the shadow DOM, but can be wrapped.

Comment: The use a hidden ``<table>`` where you duplicate the content; then find the highest column

Comment: @run_the_race Have you tried assigning `display:grid` to the `wc-column` element? That should actually solve the alignment issue.

Comment: @run_the_race N data as a key-value pair to the componente. You can then map the row without any problems and the question of the height of the cell does not arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm understanding the question correctly, what you want is so that all the rows have equal height right? if so, you just need to add `display: grid` to both `#CONTAINER` and `:host` like this:

```js
class Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE");
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    if (this.initialised) return; // Prevent initialising twice is item is moved
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.initialised = true;
      this.init();
    });
  }
  get(id) {
    return this.shadowRoot.getElementById(id);
  }
  init(required = true) {
    const prev = this.previousElementSibling;
    let props = JSON.parse(prev.textContent);
    this.props = props;
  }
  set props(value) {
    this.get('TEXTAREA1').textContent = value.textarea1;
    this.get('TEXTAREA2').textContent = value.textarea2;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('wc-column', Component);
```

```css
#CONTAINER {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE">
<style>
    :host {
        border: 1px solid lime;
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    }
    #TEXTAREA1, #TEXTAREA2 {
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div id="TEXTAREA1"></div>
<div id="TEXTAREA2"></div>
</template>

<div id="CONTAINER">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "textarea1": "Cell A1",
      "textarea2": "Cell A2"
    }
  </script>
  <wc-column></wc-column>
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "textarea1": "Cell B1 - Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum",
      "textarea2": "Cell B2 - Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum"
    }
  </script>
  <wc-column></wc-column>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I just realized that above solution will create equal heights for all of the rows (not just equal per row, but for all rows). There is another way (which is more hacky) by using `display: contents`. We can add the `display: contents` to the `wc-column` so that the children of that element is treated as if they're direct children of the container, thus applying the grid layout:

```js
class Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE");
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    if (this.initialised) return; // Prevent initialising twice is item is moved
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.initialised = true;
      this.init();
    });
  }
  get(id) {
    return this.shadowRoot.getElementById(id);
  }
  init(required = true) {
    const prev = this.previousElementSibling;
    let props = JSON.parse(prev.textContent);
    this.props = props;
  }
  set props(value) {
    this.get('TEXTAREA1').textContent = value.textarea1;
    this.get('TEXTAREA2').textContent = value.textarea2;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('wc-column', Component);
```

```css
#CONTAINER {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE">
<style>
    :host {
        border: 1px solid lime; 
        display:contents
    }
    #TEXTAREA1, #TEXTAREA2 {
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div id="TEXTAREA1"></div>
<div id="TEXTAREA2"></div>
</template>

<div id="CONTAINER">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "textarea1": "Cell A1",
      "textarea2": "Cell A2"
    }
  </script>
  <wc-column></wc-column>
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "textarea1": "Cell B1 - Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum",
      "textarea2": "Cell B2 - Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum"
    }
  </script>
  <wc-column></wc-column>
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "textarea1": "Cell C1 - Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum",
      "textarea2": "Cell C2 - Long text that overflow and requires extra vertical height because it is so long, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsu, lorem ipsummmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, lorem ipsum"
    }
  </script>
  <wc-column></wc-column>
</div>
```

But with this method, please note that if you want to add another TEXTAREA to the template, you also need to add more `auto` to the `grid-template-rows: auto auto` (e.g. 3 rows/3 TEXTAREA, then `grid-template-rows: auto auto auto`

Comment: I thought I wrote this comment, but its not here, `display: contents` is like exactly what I need, its a pity the support looks so bad: https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents, but from I understand is some edge cases, and should be okay most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

### Let CSS do the work:

- style each `<grid-cell>` with *inherited* height
- use CSS properties **on the `<spread-sheet>`** to control all Row Heights

  [image]

  [image]

**https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/y7aum2zo/**

```html
<style>
  spread-sheet {
    --rowsheight: 2em;
    display: grid;
    grid: var(--rowsizes, repeat(var(--rows), 1fr))/repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
    gap: 2px;
  }
  grid-cell {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    color: gold;
  }
</style>
<spread-sheet rows="6" columns="4"></spread-sheet>
<script>
  console.clear();
  customElements.define("spread-sheet", class extends HTMLElement {
    getrowheight(row = "s", el = this) {
      return getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(`--row${row}height`);
    }
    setrowheight(row = "s", h = "var(--rowsheight)") {
      this.style.setProperty(`--row${row}height`, h);
    }
    connectedCallback(rows, columns) {
      this.style.setProperty("--rows", rows = ~~this.getAttribute("rows") || 5);
      this.style.setProperty("--columns", columns = ~~this.getAttribute("columns") || 5);
      let rowsizes = [];
      this.append(...Array(rows).fill(0).map((_, rowidx) => {
        rowsizes.push(`var(--row${rowidx+1}height)`);
        this.setrowheight(rowidx + 1);
        return Array(columns).fill(0).map((_, colidx) => {
          let column = String.fromCharCode(65 + colidx);
          let row = rowidx + 1;
          return Object.assign(document.createElement("grid-cell"), {
            id: column + row, column, colidx, row, rowidx
          });
        })
      }).flat());
      this.style.setProperty("--rowsizes", rowsizes.join(" "));
    }
  });
  customElements.define("grid-cell", class extends HTMLElement {
    get spreadsheet() {
      return this.closest("spread-sheet");
    }
    get rowheight() {
      return ~~(this.spreadsheet.getrowheight(this.row).replace("px", ""));
    }
    set rowheight(v) {
      this.spreadsheet.setrowheight(this.row, String(v).replace("px", "") + "px");
    }
    get cellheight() {
      return ~~(getComputedStyle(this).height.replace("px", ""));
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.style.height = `max(var(--row${this.row}height),var(--rowsheight))`;
      this.innerHTML = this.id;
      new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
        for (let entry of entries)
          if (this.id == entry.target.id) this.resized();
      }).observe(this);
      // test code
      if (this.rowidx % 4 && this.colidx % 2) this.rowheight = "70px";
      if (this.id == "B6") this.resize(120);
    }
    resize(v) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.rowheight = Math.max(this.rowheight, v);
        //console.log(this.id, this.rowheight, this.cellheight);
      })
    }
    resized() {
      //console.log(`resized ${this.id} to `, this.rowheight);
      this.innerHTML = this.rowheight;
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### Communication across shadowRoots

- the ResizeObserver will check for DOM changes
- emit a `CustomEvent` (via a EventBus) to your other *listening* components
- or set the `--rowNheight` CSS variables at a higher common parentNode

Comment: Thanks for the answer Danny, The rows need to be sized according to their content, instead of some preset height. When I replace some textContent in your code example, I get `ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded`. But the concept of using events to change CSS custom properties which change the layout is still very clever, and I am sure I will use it one day. Thank you!